# Order of statements in foreach loops

Tags: foreach

When I deal with more then one statement in `foreach` loops, it seems that LaTeX deals differently with the order of the statements than I thougt.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\b}{1}
\foreach \i in {1,2} {
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\a}{\b+1}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\b}{\a}
    \a
    }
\end{document}
```

The output should be `2 3` but it is `2 2`. How can this be done?

Comment: The changes within a `\foreach` loop are local and get lost at the end. So `\b` has always value 1 at the beginning of each iteration.

Comment: can the canges somehow be done global?

Comment: Use `{\b+\i}` instaed of `{\b+1}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The changes within a `\foreach` loop are local and get lost at the end. So `\b` has value 1 at the beginning of each iteration.

The tikz way around it is to use the `remember` key.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\b}{1}
\foreach \i [remember=\b as \b] in {1,2} {
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\a}{\b+1}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\b}{\a}
    \a
    }
\end{document}
```

Using all options of the `remember` key you can write your code more succinctly as

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
\foreach \i [remember=\a as \b (initially 1)] in {1,2} {
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\a}{\b+1}
    \a
    }
\end{document}
```

For the details see the tikz manual.

You can bypass tikz and make global assignments. Note that `\b` is already in use, so redefining it globally may have unintended side effects.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand\b{1}
\foreach \i in {1,2} {
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\a}{\b+1}
    \xdef\b{\a}
    \a
    }
\end{document}
```